# Python <class 'casadi.casadi.SX'> to json object

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a JSON object in Python with a vector of type `<class 'casadi.casadi.SX'>`. The vector looks like this: `x = SX([C_a, C_b, T_R, T_K])`.

```
import json
obj = {
    "states":
    {
        "Name": x[0],
        "value": 23
    }
}
```

The name field should show the first element of `x`, i.e. `C_a` when I `print json.dumps(obj)`, but Python gives me an error

> TypeError: SX(C_a) is not JSON serializable

Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: please let us see the source code which go wrong

Comment: Thank you for replying but I fixed the problem :) I used a custom encoder to encode data types which are not supported by json.

Comment: u can post ur solution as an answer and save the next questioner's trouble~